# How is charge measured and mass of the electron at the same time?

Tags: experimental-physics, physical-constants, metrology

1. There are few constants that usually come together, $e/m$ also $h/e$. How are they decoupled?
2. If the speed of light is "derived" as [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light) states how meter defined and time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the history on the unit of time have a look at [this link](http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/second.html).

> The second is the duration of 9 192 631 770 periods of the radiation corresponding to the transition between the two hyperfine levels of the ground state of the cesium 133 atom.

In the same click on *meter* to get the definition of a meter.

> ```
> The meter is the length of the path travelled by light in vacuum during a time interval of 1/299 792 458 of a second.
>   Note that the effect of this definition is to fix the speed of light in vacuum at exactly 299 792 458 m·s-1.
> ```

[Have a look](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_charge) at the paragraph *Experimental measurements of the elementary charge* . The [oil drop experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oil-drop_experiment) has been repeated in innumerable under graduate lab courses.

> The [kilogram is the unit of mass](http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/kilogram.html); it is equal to the mass of the international prototype of the kilogram

Once the charge of an electron is known, a simple experiment with a magnetic field and a measurement of the radius will give its mass.

In this image of a bubble chamber materialization of an electron positron pair 
[image: electron positron]

there is energy loss due to electromagnetic collisions of the electron .When the experiment is carried out in vacuum with electrons  [the mass can be](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass-to-charge_ratio) measured.
[image: electron radius]

It is very seldom in physics experiments that two quantities can be measured at the same time. The measurements are done sequentially building logically on previous knowledge.

[Here is an experiment](http://www.phys.ksu.edu/personal/rprice/BB.pdf) measuring h.

> The experiment used a black body approach to experimentally measure Planck’s
>   reduced constant,  by using the Planck Radiation Law, which relates the intensity and wavelength of light to the temperature of the emitting black body. The measurement was accomplished by using a simplified detection system involving a photodiode and diffraction grating to measure the intensity of emitted light as a function of the wavelength. From the experiment it was found that the value h_bar of was 2.8±1.5x10^-35 Js.